# Docker. Run local tests from container

Tags: docker, robotframework

I need to create docker image, which will be describe only which tools needs to be installed.

Then, I want to start container from that image and run tests ( which is based on Robot Framework) and get logs in my local machine. Is it possible? If possible - how?

If it is not possible, how to create image so that I don't need to rebuild it after every change in code?

For example, I have Test Suite with 10 tests, if i build image, I cant just add test to test suite, I need to rebuild it, how to force docker "watch" for any changes?

Long story short - I need to run tests ( amount of tests will always increase) from isolated end ( docker container) - how can i do it?

This is my first docker experience.

Comment: This github repo might helpful 
`https://github.com/ppodgorsek/docker-robot-framework`

Answer (score 2):

I think the right solution is to build the container without the tests, and then use a mount point to make the tests available inside the container. That way the container won't actually contain any of the tests and won't need to be rebuilt.

Comment: I think it's best solution. Could you please tell me or shoe example how to use mount point?

Comment: it works perfectly on Ubuntu, but does not work on Mac. Is there another way how to implement it on Mac ?

Comment: @Grzegorzg It should work the same on both. I've used this technique on both.

Comment: but on Mac docker container does not see local files.

Comment: @Grzegorzg it works fine. You must be doing something wrong, but without seeing what you're doing it's impossible to help you. Please update your question with more details, such as the error you're getting, the command line you're using, etc.